# Facebook User id is null after login with scope why?

Tags: null, scope, facebook-php-sdk

When I produce a Login url with scope the getUser() returns 0;
Without parameters in getLoginUrl(); it returns a user id.

```
  $userID = $facebook->getUser();
  $params = array();
  $params['scope'] = 'email, user_about_me, user_events';
  $params['redirect_uri'] = $appurl;


  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params); // doesnt work
  //$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); // works
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
  //test user
  if($userID){
```

Comment: What is the documented behaviour? What behaviour do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'redirect_uri' => $appurl,
        'scope' => 'email, user_about_me, user_events',
    )
);
```